# How do i switch video display output command line?

Tags: hardware, display

How do i switch my video card output on Ubuntu Server 11.10? It has a video card with one DVI and one VGA. It's defaulting to the VGA. I want it to default to the DVI.

I only have ssh connection via the network and no monitor until i can switch to the DVI output.

What's the command or config file i have to mess with to switch to the DVI output on the Video Card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `xrandr`. With no commands it will list the different options you have. Then you can choose the one you need:

```
xrandr

xrandr --help

xrandr --output HDMI-0
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how to use `xrandr` for switching displays, here is a small script that I use to switch between my PC and TV monitor (the script enforces that only a single screen is active to avoid windows popping up on the wrong display).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PC=DVI-I-1
TV=HDMI-0

SWITCH_TO_PC_ARGS="--output $PC --mode 1920x1080 --primary --output $TV --off"
SWITCH_TO_TV_ARGS="--output $TV --mode 1920x1080 --primary --output $PC --off"

if [ "$1" == "pc" ]; then
  echo "Switching to PC" >> /tmp/switch_screen.log
  xrandr $SWITCH_TO_PC_ARGS 2>&1 >> /tmp/switch_screen.log

elif [ "$1" == "tv" ]; then
  echo "Switching to TV" >> /tmp/switch_screen.log
  xrandr $SWITCH_TO_TV_ARGS 2>&1 >> /tmp/switch_screen.log

else
  echo "Usage `basename $0` [tv|pc]"
  exit 1
fi
```